# Convert these strings of GMT time/date to UTC time/date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-conversion, moment-timezone

I have two strings which represent the date/time in [Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) which I wish to convert to their [Coordinated Universal Time (or UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) equivalent.

1. `2019-11-01 09:58`
2. `2019-10-01 08:58`

For the first string the time should remain the same when converted to UTC, as [Daylight saving time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is not used in November.

Whereas the time from the second string should change to 1 hour earlier when converted to UTC, as DST is used in early October.

I would like to convert both of these strings with [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and [moment-timezone.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

So far, I've tried the below without success, any suggestions?

```js
var format = 'D MMMM Y HH:mm';

console.log(
  "First momement() call should return value with 09:58 and next one with 08:58': ",'\n',
  moment("2019-11-01 09:58", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').tz('GMT').utc().format(format),'\n',
  moment("2019-10-01 09:58", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').tz('GMT').utc().format(format)
);

console.log(
  "First momement() call should return value with 09:58 and next one with 08:58': ",'\n',
  moment.tz("2019-11-01 09:58", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',"GMT").utc().format(format),'\n',
  moment.tz("2019-10-01 09:58", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',"GMT").utc().format(format)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.5/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [There's no meaningful difference between the two](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQ5EfJhsjYaZ6MxdBlfDGi8RStzaQ%3A1572291036841&source=hp&ei=3EG3XdryMIbB-wTg-qTYAg&q=difference+between+utc+and+gmt&btnK=Google+Search&oq=measure+run+time+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i20i263j0l3j0i22i30l6.482.3766..4919...1.0..0.201.2147.1j16j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j35i39j0i67j0i10.mnaSR3X-FR8). Neither change for DST: they are always the same time. One is a timezone, and the other is a standard, but they refer to the same clock time.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I found out what it was.  Instead of using `GMT` to convert it, I needed to use the timezone location/place.

```js
var format = 'D MMMM Y HH:mm';

console.log(
  "First momement() call should return value with 09:58 and next one with 08:58': ",'\n',
  moment.tz("2019-11-01 09:58", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm','Europe/London').utc().format(format),'\n',
  moment.tz("2019-10-01 09:58", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm','Europe/London').utc().format(format)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.5/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```